# How to add newline to contents in file using FileWriter

Tags: java

I am trying to write newline separated data in the text file using the following code:

```
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=null;
    FileWriter fileWriter=null;


    ArrayList<String> count=new ArrayList<>();
    count.add("2");
    count.add("4");
    fileWriter=new FileWriter(fileName);

    bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(count));
    PrintWriter printWriter=new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    printWriter.write(count + "\n");

    bufferedWriter.close();
    printWriter.close();
```

But the problem is the data that is being written is like this :

```
[2, 4][2, 4]
```

How can I have data that is like this :

```
2
4
3
54
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) over explicit closes. Also, I would use a [`for-each` loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) to iterate the values in the `List` (and program to the *interface*). Like,

```
List<String> count = Arrays.asList("2", "4", "3", "54");
try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new FileWriter(fileName)))) {
    for (String s : count) {
        pw.println(s);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'\n' is the Unix newline. On Windows, it's "\r\n", you need to use System.lineSeparator() or "%n" inside a String.format to use whichever one is appropriate for your system. You are printing to the same file twice using the BufferedReader and PrintReader which is very weird. Why do you need both?. You are only writing 2 and 4 obviously because that's all is in your data.

You have a ton of unnecessary stuff in your code. Just initialize when you declare your variable.

```
List<String> count = Arrays.asList("2", "4", "3", "54");
try(PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new File(fileName)){
        count.stream().forEach(printWriter::println);
} // auto-closes the streams
```

What you want could be written like this, so you don't need to do the newline at all as println handles it for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=null;
    FileWriter fileWriter=null;

    ArrayList<String> count=new ArrayList<>();
    count.add("2");
    count.add("4");
    count.add("3");
    count.add("54");
    fileWriter=new FileWriter(fileName);


    bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

    for(int i = 0;i < count.size();i++){
        bufferedWriter.write(String.valueOf(count.get(i)) + "\n");
    }

    bufferedWriter.close();
```